# The SQL command to call the procedure, passing the orderID of 2000

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Purchases (In orderID int)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT orderId, orderdate, partNum,numOrdered,price
        from hscust, hslineitem
        where orderId = orderID;
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to call the procedure and pass the orderID of 2000?

Comment: `CALL Purchases(2000)`

Comment: You should not give the same names to parameters as columns - mysql will test <tablename>.orderid against <tablename>.orderid and always get a match. Also don't use comma joins and do qualify all columns with their tablenames.

Answer (score 0):

Once your stored procedure is ready and doesn't have any syntax error you can call the stored procedure by using below statement.

syntax: CALL {STORED_PROC_NAME}([params_in_order_defined])
example: CALL Purchases(2000)